# Phantomjs fails on new File

Tags: phantomjs, karma-jasmine

When I try to run karma tests using phantomjs in my angular2 application 
I get this error. When I use  chrome as karams browser it works.

```
TypeError: FileConstructor is not a constructor (evaluating 'new File(["file"], "filename")') (line 35)
```

Comment: Solved this by using headless chrome instead of phantomjs